# In an object of type List<T>, does accessing an object by index run through each item in the list, or does it use a much faster approach?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
...
// add lots of members...
...
MyClass myClass = myList[25];
```

Will asking for index 25 take much longer than asking for index 1, or does it use some quick algorithm to jump straight to the 25th item?

Thanks!

Comment: Accessing a List<T> item by index is O(1) but not removing by [`RemoveAt` which is O(n)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is implemented as array (which grows when you're adding new items) so accessing of n-th element will be O(1) operation. (Therefore there will be no difference in speed between getting `myList[1]` and `myList[25]`.)

Excerpt from the [`List<T>.Item` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx) documentation:

> Retrieving the value of this property is an O(1) operation; setting the property is also an O(1) operation.

I can imagine how slow would be .NET applications if `List<T>` had to jump through all items before getting n-th...

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "which grows when you're adding new items" - whilst the List<> can grow the underlying array cannot: instead the array is replaced with a new, larger array and the contents copied across.  Thus a List<> grows by using additional elements of the underlying array or, when these are exhausted, by creating a new, larger array.

Comment: @Paul Ruane, thank you for your comment, your are absolutely right (it creates a new doubled in size array each time it runs out of current capacity); I just wanted to keep the answer simple.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx) property of `List<T>`

> Retrieving the value of this property is an O(1) operation; setting the property is also an O(1) operation.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's **very** fast. In fact it's not an algorithm at all*; the backing store for `List<T>` is just a `T[]` array; so all it has to do is jump to a known location in memory.

In abstract terms, think of it like this: since the elements of an array reside in a contiguous block of memory, you can imagine the array as a number line. Does it take you any longer to find "10" on a number line than "1"? No -- you know exactly how the numbers are laid out, so all you have to do is look straight at 10. You don't have to scroll your eyes through 1, 2, 3, etc., in other words.

Granted, that's a highly non-technical analogy; but it's pretty consistent with how accessing an element of an array works.

<sub>*A *calculation* is required, yes: the address of the first element in the array plus the product the element size with the index. But to call this an "algorithm" would be a stretch; and anyway, it is a constant-time operation regardless.</sub>

Comment: A small, and very pedantic, nitpick: A calculation *is* required, just not at the C#/IL level. Something like `addressOfElement = baseAddress + (index * sizeOfElement)`. This is, as you say, blindingly fast and constant regardless of index (if we disregard ultra-nitpicky concerns like whether the required element is currently in cache, main memory or swap etc).

Comment: @LukeH: Yeah, valid point. I guess whether this conflicts with my answer depends on how strict your definition of "algorithm" is. I'd still stick by my analogy, though, as one could say that in order to be able to immediately "find" a point on a line you would at least need to know what units you're working with (`sizeOfElement` in your example).

Answer (score 0):

No, *removing* and *insertion* on the other hand is dependent on where you remove an element, since it is a **dynamic array**.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` uses `T[]` internally so indexing is supported directly by the underlying data structure.